# PHP BlackJack random card on button click

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to make a BlackJack game using PHP but I've come across the following problem:

I made the following array:

```
function random_card(){
    $cards = array(
    1           =>  1,
    2           =>  2,
    3           =>  3,
    4           =>  4,
    5           =>  5,
    6           =>  6,
    7           =>  7,
    8           =>  8,
    9           =>  9,
    10          =>  10,
    'Jack'      =>  10,
    'Queen'     =>  10,
    'King'      =>  10,
    'Ace'       =>  11);

    $card = array_rand($cards);
    $points = $cards[$card];
    echo 'card: ' . $card . '<br>';
    echo 'points: ' . $points . '<br><br>';
}

echo random_card();
```

This is just the start, it will show me a random card and the points. (I don't know if this is the best way to do this, but it works)

Now I need a button named 'hit' and when pressed it needs to give me a second card. I know you can't use a PHP function on a button so it should be a javascript onClick() event. But how do i combine the both of them to give me another card next to the one i already have.

I already tried using a submit button, this way you can add php code to it but it keeps overwriting my old card. It keeps randomizing the first card.

And I doubt using a submit button $_POST for giving me a card is the best solution here.

I appreciate any help pushing me in the right direction since im not really experienced in javascript and php.

Comment: use a combination of ajax and json

Comment: It's not directly relevant to your question, but your example of using the array of card options is somewhat flawed because 1) An ace can be worth 1 or 11 at any time, so having a separate option for both forces the value (so that someone could be dealt a 1 and a King, which would be 21 if it was a variable value ace), and 2) you only are dealing the value of the card, not the suit. The suit isn't important in BJ, but it does multiply the possible cards dealt by 4. Right now there is a 1 in 14 chance of getting an Ace, vs a 1 in 52 chance in a real deck.

Comment: @Anthony You're absolutely right. But i'm working my way up from the very start. Which is letting a button deal you a random card. If this works ill make it so that it counts the point and if its 22 or higher you're busted etc. Don't worry im working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are more familiar with javascript, use Sharanya Dutta's simple answer.

If you prefer PHP, [SESSION](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php) will be the easiest way how to remember the state.

```
session_start(); // use session

// cards on pile
if(!isset($_SESSION["pile"])) $_SESSION["pile"] = array(
  1           =>  1,
  2           =>  2,
  3           =>  3,
  4           =>  4,
  5           =>  5,
  6           =>  6,
  7           =>  7,
  8           =>  8,
  9           =>  9,
  10          =>  10,
  'Jack'      =>  10,
  'Queen'     =>  10,
  'King'      =>  10,
  'Ace'       =>  11);

// cards in hand
if(!isset($_SESSION["hand"])) $_SESSION["hand"] = array();

// draw a card from the pile into the hand
function draw_card() {
  $card = array_rand($_SESSION["pile"]);
  $_SESSION["hand"][$card] = $_SESSION["pile"][$card];
  unset($_SESSION["pile"][$card]);
}

function list_hand() {
  foreach($_SESSION["hand"] as $card=>$points) {
    echo 'card: ' . $card . '<br>';
    echo 'points: ' . $points . '<br><br>';
  }
}

// detect which form was triggered
function FORM($value) {
  return isset($_POST["form"]) && $_POST["form"]==$value;
}

// handle the draw form
if(FORM("draw")) draw_card();
list_hand();
?>

<form method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="form" value="draw">
  <input type="submit" value="Draw a card">
</form>
```

Comment: I will select your answer as best answer since, i'm really trying to improve my PHP and try to do as much as possible with PHP. So thanks alot for tkaing your time and help me!

Comment: When all cards are drawn it will send a final `card: 
points: ` with a `Undefined index: in` on the top of the page. Is there a quick way to prevent this?

Comment: Dont mind this last comment, it won't occur that someone draws all cards. But one problem is where do i need to end the session. So that if i refresh the page it will empty the page again?

Comment: @Farewyth: no, session vars are persistent [for 3 hours by default](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-expire.php). Every time you write a session var it is serialized on the server. When you read the data after refresh, it's value is restored by unserialization from the server. Every visitor has his own unique session id stored as cookie or in url. You can also manually destroy or end the session vars, start reading [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php).

Answer (score 2):

You may do it with pure javascript:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var cards = new Array(
    new Array(1, 1),
    new Array(2, 2),
    new Array(3, 3),
    new Array(4, 4),
    new Array(5, 5),
    new Array(6, 6),
    new Array(7, 7),
    new Array(8, 8),
    new Array(9, 9),
    new Array(10, 10),
    new Array("Jack", 10),
    new Array("Queen", 10),
    new Array("King", 10),
    new Array("Ace", 11)
);
function random_card(){
    if(cards.length > 0){
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*cards.length);
    var html = "card: "+cards[rand][0]+"<br/>points: "+cards[rand][1]+"<br/><br/>";
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML += html;
    cards.splice(rand, 1);
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<button onclick="random_card();">Hit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TT7JK/

Comment: Amazing! Didn't know JS arrays could work like this aswell. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Farewyth then please accept this answer to let others know you already found a working solution. If you are interested in PHP way, have a look at my answer: I believe you may find it useful as well.

Answer (score 1):

send current card id like 'King' with hit request.

And chek the random card not equal with given card Id.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to maintain and remember the state, and mark the cards already given to the user. You can do it through a database like MySQl or just use caching or
encrypted cookie to store previously delivered cards.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need a cookie or database; you can just store the card(s) in the [$_SESSION](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) variable. This way would not require AJAX either.